# Connect SSH MySQL server from Windows

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin

I have installed MySQL on Ubuntu using SSH and would like to connect [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) installed on a Windows machine.

I tried to add a server like standard server, but I can not log in to MySQL server using SSH.
Does phpMyAdmin support to connect a remote server using SSH? If yes, how can I configure a private key for phpMyAdmin or do I need a SSH client for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding that might be hindering you sorting this out.

SSH is the Secure Shell protocol, which allows a user to remotely access the command line of a server. You can access MySQL via SSH by using SSH to start a command line session on the server and using the `mysql` command line client as if you were at the machine directly.

phpMyAdmin can connect to a local MySQL instance (where MySQL and your webserver run on the same machine) or connect to another machine through the network (where MySQL is running on one machine and your webserver is running on another -- the connection in this case is via the the port used by MySQL itself, 3306). In either case, you can access phpMyAdmin itself from any browser on the network; it just appears as any web page. The communication between MySQL and phpMyAdmin can be encrypted (via SSL) if you wish, but still happens via MySQL communication and not over SSH. At no point is SSH used for the communication from the web server to the MySQL server.

So in your case, since you wish to install phpMyAdmin on the Windows box, you'd simply edit your config.inc.php to connect to the IP address or hostname of the Ubuntu server with the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'hostname';` directive, using the actual hostname instead. You'd then access phpMyAdmin from anywhere on the network by using the hostname or IP address of the Windows machine.

If, instead, you wish to install phpMyAdmin on to the Ubuntu machine, you could use the host name 'localhost' in config.inc.php and then access phpMyAdmin from the Windows machine (or any other machine) using the Ubuntu IP address/host name in your web browser.

It all depends which machine you wish to be the web server. phpMyAdmin runs under IIS or Apache runs under Windows, but Ubuntu makes installing all the programs easy through the package manager, so that's what I generally do in this situation.

Hope that helps clear it up a bit.